# When can Java produce a NaN?

Tags: java, nan

I know what Java `Double.NaN` is.  I have some Java code that produces `NaN`.

```
// calculate errors
delta = m1 + m2 - M;
eta = f1 + f2 - F;
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
  epsilon[i] = p[i]*m1+(1-p[i])*m2+q[i]*f1+(1-q[i])*f2-C[i];
}

// use errors in gradient descent
// set aside differences for the p's and q's
float mDiff = m1 - m2;
float fDiff = f1 - f2;
// first update m's and f's
m1 -= rate*delta;
m2 -= rate*delta;
f1 -= rate*eta;
f2 -= rate*eta;
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
  m1 -= rate*epsilon[i]*p[i];
  m2 -= rate*epsilon[i]*(1-p[i]);
  f1 -= rate*epsilon[i]*q[i];
  f2 -= rate*epsilon[i]*(1-q[i]);
}
// now update the p's and q's
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
  p[i] -= rate*epsilon[i]*mDiff;
  q[i] -= rate*epsilon[i]*fDiff;  
}
```

Under what circumstances will Java produce a NaN value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given what I know about gradient descent, you are most probably jumping out to infinity because you do not have adaptive `rate` (i.e. your `rate` is too big).

Comment: You are completely correct.  I trimmed the rate and now it is well behaved -- color me embarrassed to not think of the obvious thing first.

Answer (score 43):

`NaN` is triggered by the following occurrences:

- results that are complex values

  - √x where x is negative
  - log(x) where x is negative
  - tan(x) where x mod 180 is 90
  - asin(x) or acos(x) where x is outside [-1..1]
- 0/0
- ∞/∞
- ∞/−∞
- −∞/∞
- −∞/−∞
- 0×∞
- 0×−∞
- 1<sup>∞</sup>
- ∞ + (−∞)
- (−∞) + ∞

Sorry for such a general answer, but I hope that helped.

Comment: Well, from this list I can clearly deduce it must be one of the ones involving addition or multiplications, so I guess it boils down to hunting for where something overflows.

Comment: For those curious, like me, why is 1^∞ there: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56006.html

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia:

> There are three kinds of operation which return `NaN`:
>
> - Operations with a `NaN` as at least one operand
> - Indeterminate forms
>
>   - The divisions 0/0, ∞/∞, ∞/−∞, −∞/∞, and −∞/−∞
>   - The multiplications 0×∞ and 0×−∞
>   - The power 1<sup>∞</sup>
>   - The additions ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ and equivalent subtractions.
> - Real operations with complex results:
>
>   - The square root of a negative number
>   - The logarithm of a negative number
>   - The tangent of an odd multiple of 90 degrees (or π/2 radians)
>   - The inverse sine or cosine of a number which is less than −1 or greater than +1.

This Java snippet illustrates all of the above, except the tangent one (I suspect because of limited precision of `double`):

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Double.NaN;
import static java.lang.Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
import static java.lang.Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

public class NaN {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double[] allNaNs = {
            0D/0D,
            POSITIVE_INFINITY / POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            POSITIVE_INFINITY / NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            NEGATIVE_INFINITY / POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            NEGATIVE_INFINITY / NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            0 * POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            0 * NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            Math.pow(1, POSITIVE_INFINITY),
            POSITIVE_INFINITY + NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            NEGATIVE_INFINITY + POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            POSITIVE_INFINITY - POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            NEGATIVE_INFINITY - NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
            Math.sqrt(-1),
            Math.log(-1),
            Math.asin(-2),
            Math.acos(+2),
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allNaNs));
        // prints "[NaN, NaN...]"
        System.out.println(NaN == NaN); // prints "false"
        System.out.println(Double.isNaN(NaN)); // prints "true"
    }
}
```

#### References

- [Wikipedia/NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)
- [JLS 15.21.1 Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.21.1)

  > If either operand is `NaN`, then the result of `==` is `false` but the result of `!=` is `true`. Indeed, the test `x!=x` is `true` if and only if the value of `x` is `NaN`. (The methods `Float.isNaN` and `Double.isNaN` may also be used to test whether a value is `NaN`.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sprinkling your code with `System.out.println` statements to determine *exactly* where NaNs start occuring?

Comment: I had done many, but not everything.  I've done everything now and it seems to be that the gradient can push everything off to infinity, so I'll probably have to add some ad-hoc method to push it back.