# Comprehensive list of ways to generate NaN in Java?

Tags: java, nan

I've been facing a problem with NaN causing exceptions in a project I'm working on. I was wondering if somebody could provide a list of all of the possible ways an NaN might surface in Java, so I could know all of the possible things to look for while tracking it down.

Comment: You can post your code! We can work on the issue and it will be a lot easier for everyone to help you out in the best way.

Comment: I have a fairly large code base, and I'm honestly not sure what code is relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can Java produce a NaN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887131/when-can-java-produce-a-nan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2887161/546060

`NaN` is triggered by the following occurrences:

- results that are complex values

  - √x where x is negative
  - log(x) where x is negative
  - tan(x) where x mod 180 is 90
  - asin(x) or acos(x) where x is outside [-1..1]
- 0/0
- ∞/∞
- ∞/−∞
- −∞/∞
- −∞/−∞
- 0×∞
- 0×−∞
- 1<sup>∞</sup>
- ∞ + (−∞)
- (−∞) + ∞

Comment: Surprised I couldn't find that thread when I was trying to figure this out earlier. Thanks, that should (hopefully) help locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some:

```
Double.NaN + Double.NaN  ->  NaN
Float.NaN + 2.0  ->  NaN
Float.NaN * 3.0  ->  NaN
(0.0 / 0.0) * Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY  ->  NaN
Math.abs(0.0 / 0.0) -> NaN
```

Taken from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20021210222933/http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm).

Comment: Um of course calculations that begin with NaN result in NaN.